# joomla url rewrite more friendly?

Tags: seo, joomla

I have url structure like index.php?option=mycomponent&id=12

I would like to rewrite id=12 to something like "blue car" where blue car I can place somewhere in mysql.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The core Joomla SEF URLs build urls based on the alias of your article/menu item. Instead of yourdomain.com/index.php?option=mycomponent&id=12 it would be yourdomain.com/blue-car

To turn that on:

1. In the root of the directory Joomla is installed in and look for htaccess.txt and rename it .htaccess
2. In the admin > global configuration > site tab look for SEO settings and turn them all on (unless you dont want the .html extensions, that one is optional)

Comment: I know how to turn on SEO in Joomla but looking for the solution to rewrites my own names instead of ID's

Comment: Joomla SEO URLs don't contain IDs at all. You can control what shows up in the URLs with the alias of the content.

Comment: If you are talking about SEO URLs for your custom component, then you need to write the router that tells Joomla how to handle your URLs. See http://docs.joomla.org/Routing

Answer (score 0):

If you have some $ to spend definitely look into [sh404SEF extension for Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134), terrific component.

If not then stick to Joomla's native SEF, see [Joomla's SEF URLs tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/SEF_URLs_in_Joomla!_1.5).